Product of particular lengths of quadrilateral inscribed in circle

Prove that $AF\times ED\times BC=FE\times DC\times BA$
I have added my solution as an answer.
I am looking for more intuitive answers.

I can't think of any descriptive title. Title edits are welcome.

Could you tell the origin of this problem ?

@JeanMarie It was given to me by one of my teachers. Seems to be a page from some textbook, don’t know for sure though. Maybe some Olympiad… Original image


Case 1: $BG\parallel DC$ and $AB\parallel GC$
$\angle ACB=\angle AGF$
$\angle BAC=\angle BGC\overset{BG\parallel DC}=\angle GCD =\angle GAF$
Thus, $\triangle AFG\sim \triangle ABC$
Thus, $\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AF}{FG}$
Substituting $FG$ from the previous equation into $\frac{FG}{FE}=\frac{DC}{DE}$ (from $\triangle FGE\sim \triangle DCE$):
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AF\times DE}{DC\times FE}$$
Which, upon rearrangement gives our desired equation.


Case 2: $BG\nparallel DC$ or $AB\nparallel GC$
WLOG, assume $BG\nparallel DC$. $BG$ and $DC$ meet at $P$
$$\begin{align}
\frac{PG}{PC}&=\frac{GD}{BC}\\
\therefore\frac{PG}{PC}\times\frac{GF}{GD}&=\frac{GF}{BC}\\
\therefore\frac{PG}{PC}\times\frac{AF}{AB}&=\frac{GF}{BC}\text{ [$\because \triangle GFD\sim\triangle AFB$]}\\
\therefore \frac{PG}{PC\times GF}&=\frac{AB}{AF\times BC}
\end{align}$$
Using the weak Menelaus' theorem in $\triangle PFD$ with line $GC$:
$$\frac{FE\times CD\times PG}{FD\times PC\times GF}=1$$
Substituting the value of $\frac{PG}{PC\times GF}$ into the previous equation:
$$\frac{FE\times CD\times AB}{FD\times AF\times BC}=1$$
Which is our required equation.
